# How to toggle multiple html text elements using Vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use the most efficient method of toggling the innerHTML on multiple  elements. I am still learning and have gotten stuck at this point

```js
var button = document.querySelectorAll(".title");

for (i=0; i < button.length; i++) {
  button[i].addEventListener('click', textToggle)
}

function textToggle() {
  if (button.getAttribute("data-text-swap") == button.innerHTML) {
    button.innerHTML = button.getAttribute("data-text-original");
  } else {
    button.setAttribute("data-text-original", button.innerHTML);
    button.innerHTML = button.getAttribute("data-text-swap");
  }
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary class="title" data-text-swap="Hide text">
  Show text
  </summary>
    <p>text</p>
</details>

<details>
  <summary class="title" data-text-swap="Hide text">
  Show text
  </summary>
    <p>text</p>
</details>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. You just need to operate on the `e.target` element, which is the element associated with the `click` event, and not the `button` variable which is a list of elements.

```js
var button = document.querySelectorAll(".title");

for (i=0; i < button.length; i++) {
  button[i].addEventListener('click', textToggle)
}

function textToggle(e) {
  const el = e.target;
  if (el.getAttribute("data-text-swap") == el.innerHTML) {
    el.innerHTML = el.getAttribute("data-text-original");
  } else {
    el.setAttribute("data-text-original", el.innerHTML);
    el.innerHTML = el.getAttribute("data-text-swap");
  }
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary class="title" data-text-swap="Hide text">
  Show text
  </summary>
    <p>text</p>
</details>

<details>
  <summary class="title" data-text-swap="Hide text">
  Show text
  </summary>
    <p>text</p>
</details>
```

Answer (score 1):

You refer to `button` that is not an element but an array. You can refer to the clicked button in the callbackwith the keyword `this`

```js
var button = document.querySelectorAll(".title");

for (i=0; i < button.length; i++) {
  button[i].addEventListener('click', textToggle)
}

function textToggle() {
  if (this.getAttribute("data-text-swap") == this.innerHTML) {
    this.innerHTML = this.getAttribute("data-text-original");
  } else {
    this.setAttribute("data-text-original", this.innerHTML);
    this.innerHTML = this.getAttribute("data-text-swap");
  }
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary class="title" data-text-swap="Hide text">
  Show text
  </summary>
    <p>text</p>
</details>

<details>
  <summary class="title" data-text-swap="Hide text">
  Show text
  </summary>
    <p>text</p>
</details>
```